# Angular Material 5 set fab button default color

Tags: angular, angular-material, floating-action-button

I am using Anuglar Material (5.0.4) and I would like the `mat-fab-button` default background color to be white like it is in the [Angular examples](https://material.angular.io/components/button/examples). However for me the background color is the accent color for some reason.

[image]

**HTML**

```xml
<h2>Fab Buttons</h2>
<div>
  <button mat-fab>Basic</button>
  <button mat-fab color="primary">Primary</button>
  <button mat-fab color="accent">Accent</button>
  <button mat-fab color="warn">Warn</button>
  <button mat-fab disabled>Disabled</button>
  <button mat-fab>
    <mat-icon aria-label="Example icon-button with a whats hot icon">whatshot</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <a mat-fab routerLink=".">Link</a>
</div>

<h2>Mini Fab Buttons</h2>
<div>
  <button mat-mini-fab>Basic</button>
  <button mat-mini-fab color="primary">Primary</button>
  <button mat-mini-fab color="accent">Accent</button>
  <button mat-mini-fab color="warn">Warn</button>
  <button mat-mini-fab disabled>Disabled</button>
  <button mat-mini-fab>
    <mat-icon aria-label="Example icon-button with a whats hot icon">whatshot</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <a mat-mini-fab routerLink=".">Link</a>
</div>
```

**Theme**

```css
$deeporange-teal-amber-theme-primary: mat-palette($mat-deep-orange, 500, 100, 700);
$deeporange-teal-amber-theme-accent: mat-palette($mat-teal);
$deeporange-teal-amber-theme-warn: mat-palette($mat-amber);

$deeporange-teal-amber-theme: mat-light-theme(
  $deeporange-teal-amber-theme-primary,
  $deeporange-teal-amber-theme-accent,
  $deeporange-teal-amber-theme-warn);
```

The weird thing is `mat-raised-button` has a white background.

Comment: can you check in dev tools where is the background-color style coming from?

Answer (score 10):

In the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/button/overview#theming), it says about theming:

> By default, only FABs (Floating Action Button) are colored; the
>   default background color for mat-button and mat-raised-button matches
>   the theme's background color.

If you try out the example code on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/byxgxvqbolg?file=app%2Fbutton-types-example.html) you will see that the FABs without a `color` attribute are colored as well. (I don't know why the behavior of the embedded example in the docs is different.)

If you want your FABs to be white, just leave the color attribute empty:

```html
<button mat-fab color="">Basic</button>
```

Comment: The theming guide also contains a section for [theming individual components](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#theming-only-certain-components)

Comment: Ah I had misread that doc last night, I thought it applied to raised buttons as well as fabs. Still I wounder why it behaves differently in the doc examples than in the real world.

Comment: That's confusing, I agree. If you don't want to specify a color attribute every time, maybe it would be an option to create your own custom `my-fab` component that has the color set by default. I don't think the behavior of the library is going to change.

Comment: I have opened an github issue for the docs example: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/9360

Answer (score 2):

you can just style it with your desired color like this `<button style="background-color:firebrick" mat-fab>Sell</button>`